# What assumption is needed to add together equations in a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose in a vector space $V$, we have $x+z=y+z$. We want to show that $x=y$.

Note, by one of the vector space axioms, for all $z \in V$ there exists an additive inverse $v \in V$ such that for all $z+v=0$. Then, 
\begin{align*}
x&=x+0 \\
&=x+(z+v) \\
&=(x+z)+v \\
&=(y+z)+v \\
&=y+(z+v) \\
&=y+0 \\
&=y
\end{align*}

Now, you might think, like I do, that it seems simpler to prove this result by adding $v$ to both sides of the equality $x+z=y+z$, noting that $z+v=0$, and then noting that $x=y$. However, am I using an additional assumption not given by the 8 vector space axioms? What assumption is needed to essentially "add" something to both sides of the equation and for the equality to still hold? Or asked differently, what assumption is needed to "add together" two equations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need anything else: If $a = b$, then $a + c = b + c$ follows by substituting $b$ for $a$.

Comment: Okay. So start by noticing $x+z+v=x+z+v$. Then $x+z+v=(y+z)+v$ by substituting $x+z=y+z$. Then $x+(z+v)=y+(z+v)$. Then $x+0=y+0$. So $x=y$. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Right on, and you're welcome.